Что если email адрес превышает 256 символов после кодрования в base64
Здесь пишут, что максимальная длина почтового адреса в заголовках From и To включая <>, составляет 256 символов. А максимальная длина юзернейма (того, что до @)  - 64 символа. При этом здесь пишут, что юзернейм может содержать некоторые utf-8 символы до 127-го (т.е. ascii) и любые другие. Но не-ascii символы полагается кодировать в base64 (например "йцукен" -> "=?utf-8?B?0LnQudGG0YPQutC10L0=?="). Вопрос тогда, что, если изначально длина адреса вместе с <> не превышала 256, но юзернейм содержал не-ascii символы и адрес стал превышать 256 символов после кодирования юзернейма в base64? Как такие случаи обрабатывать?

Заголовки можно разбивать на несколько строк

@Alexey Ten я знаю, но зачем тогда это ограничение длины path на 256 символов? Мне кажется, это правило, которое нужно соблюдать отдельно

В заголовке To обычно ешё имя написано. "Вася Пупкин" <vasya@example.com>,  ограничение на path касаются vasya, а не всего заголовка. При это вместо Вася Пупкин можно любовную балладу вписать (утрирую конечно)

Я про это и спрашивою. Что если у меня адрес "вася@example.com" ? После того как я  path закодирую, он может стать больше 256 символов.

5322 ограничивает длину доменной части в 255 байт и длину локальной в 64 байта. Современные стандарты позволяют использовать и в локальной и доменной частях адреса (в заголовках письма) некодированный никак utf-8, коль скоро для письма заявлен 8-битный content-transfer-encoding. Display-name при этом все равно рекомендовано кодировать согласно rfc 2047.
Вот при передаче на транспорт (SMTP) и локальную и доменную части адресов (RCPT TO) рекомендуется кодировать в punycode.
Ну и наконец, соображения длины здесь вторичны. Если система получателя позволила создать пользователя с не-ascii именем в интернациональном домене, то как минимум она готова принять почту с таким адресатом. Проблемы возможны при показе в клиентском приложении получателя, но сегодня все поддерживают utf-8 и все транспорты нейтральны к 8 битам, потому я бы предпочел некодированный utf-8 в address-spec в заголовках письма.

А если я хочу для остального письма установить content-transfer-encoding: base64 например? "при передаче на транспорт" не понял, что такое передача на транспорт. Отправка письма что ли? А  где тогда не нужно кодировать в punycode?

Отдельные MIME части письма запросто могут быть base64. 8bit для некодированного письма придется задать в его заголовках (и в заголовках message/rfc822 вложенного, если там те же проблемы). Punycode нужен при передаче адресов в транспортном протоколе (в SMTP в параметрах команд RCPT TO/MAIL FROM) - если принимающий сервер не объявил поддержку UTF8..Punycode в любом случае понадобится для разбора интернационального доменного имени через DNS.

Что, если я хочу отослать закодированное письмо в base64? Т.е. весь текст закодировать. В таком случае я не могу указать content-transfer-encoding: 8bit. Что тогда делать если нужно написать на адрес вася@example.com? Если я закодирую его в base64, он может не влезть в 256 символов. То же самое с punycode. И ещё как индицировать, что строка закодирована в punycode?

Во-первых, можете указать 8bit, даже если остальным частям письма хватает 7bit.

Во-первых, можете указать 8bit, даже если остальным частям письма хватает 7bit. Во-вторых, проблема выхода длины addr-spec за некие лимиты здесь вторична, важнее - что делать с интернациональными адресами. Так вот rfc6532 прямо позволяет использовать UTF-8. В-третьих, если речь идёт о заголовках письма, а важны они клиентскому ПО для показа и худшее, что может произойти - адрес будет показан с ошибками и т.п; для собственно доставки важно то, как адрес кодируется в командах транспортного протокола, и там принятой сейчас практикой является использование punycode по rfc 3492.

Если я укажу 8bit, а содержимое закодирую в base64, например потому что там есть строки длиннее 998 символов, то получатель увидит нонсенс в виде закодированного и не раскодированного письма. Что касается punycode - а как протокол понимает, что этот адрес закодирован? И нужно ли мне вручную кодировать в punycode или это автоматически происходит при передачи письма?

Для тела письма вполне можно указать и base64. Заголовки разбираются последовательно и utf-8 в addr-spec скорее всего будет правильно разобран. В punycode такие адреса должна преобразовывать почтовая система, тот код который непосредственно общается по SMTP.
